# how to split a string using ":" and "space"?

Tags: android

I am new to android ,I need to split a string by using ":" and space .
because the string format is (ex : 08:30 PM)

If it is in 08:30:PM I can easily split it by using ":" but here I have space also.

Code :

```
 if (!(mTime == null)) {
                String timme = mTime;
                String[] time = timme.split(":");
                int hour = Integer.parseInt(time[0].trim());
                int min = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time[1].split("")).trim());
                mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                mTimePicker.setMinute(min);
            }
```

I got the below error on the  **int min = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time[1].split("")).trim());**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aviz.www.reminder/com.aviz.www.reminder.Activity_Classes.CreateAlarm}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[Ljava.lang.String;@6380103"
```

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to parse date like that. Once the date time format changes in a way, e.g. becomes 24h format or includes seconds, your code will not work anymore.. Use java date formatters instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Something doesn't sound right here.  I have worked with Android date/time pickers before, and I don't recall having to fish the time components out of a string like this.  Maybe tell us how you ended up with `08:30:PM` in the first place.

Comment: This is not right you dateFormat methods in java to format your date. This will surely crash on different date types.

Comment: I have trouble understand your source data. Where does that `08:30:PM` come from?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

In your case would be something like:

```
 if (!(mTime == null)) {
            //08:30 PM
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            //08:30:PM
            //DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m:a", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = format.parse(string);
            //now you can do whatever you want with the date
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split based on white spaces in Java. You can use for the Spaces

```
String[] words=s1.split("\\s");
```

And use this to split ":"

```
String namepass[] = strLine.split(":");
```

Comment: I doubt this will completely fix the OP, but even so you should probably split on `\\s+`, in case there could be more than one space present.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about this code

```
int min = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time[1].split("")).trim());
```

It takes second from `time` array (it's string)
After that it splits that string with empty string and

```
time[1].split("")
```

will return array of strings with 1 item.

```
String.valueOf(String[] array)
```

will return something like "[Ljava.lang.String;@6380103]" 
trim method will not change this string and that string is not a valid number so you got an exception.

My advice is to avoid complex to understand code.

I suggest to use date format to parse time from string

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!(mTime == null)) {
                    String timme = mTime;
                    timme=timme.replace( " ","");
                    String[] time = timme.split(":");
                    int hour = Integer.parseInt(time[0].trim());
                    int min = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time[1].split("")).trim());
                    mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                    mTimePicker.setMinute(min);
                }
```